# What is this line saying / doing?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've found the following line in a query and no matter how many ways I think about it I don't understand what it's intended to do... Could you please help me to understand why this would be in a where clause and how it reads in pseudo code?

```
      DATEADD(year,              
             DATEDIFF(year, Convert(datetime,upvHD.PropertyVal), GETDATE()),
             Convert(datetime,upvHD.PropertyVal) 
             ) > GETDATE()
```

Comment: I think it just sets the year part of `upvHD.PropertyVal` to current year without affecting the `month` and `date` part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression

```
DATEADD(year,              
         DATEDIFF(year, Convert(datetime,upvHD.PropertyVal), GETDATE()),
         Convert(datetime,upvHD.PropertyVal) 
         )
```

Is taking whatever date is stored in `PropertyVal` and is resetting the year portion of that date to be the same as the current year.

This is then being compared to the current date. This might be used to check whether we've gone past the anniversary of a particular date.

---

To break it down, we first have this expression:

```
DATEDIFF(year, Convert(datetime,upvHD.PropertyVal), GETDATE())
```

Which computes the number of year transitions (new years eve -> new years day) which have occurred between `PropertyVal` and the current date. Then this expression:

```
DATEADD(year,              
         <previous>,
         Convert(datetime,upvHD.PropertyVal) 
         )
```

Is adding that same number of years onto `PropertyVal`.